# In-Field Labels Don't Line Up With Input Text

Tags: css, forms

I'm using [Viget's In-Field Labels plugin](https://github.com/davist11/In-Field-Labels-jQuery-Plugin) on a form, but even though the label and input have the same font size, same line height, same height, same padding, same *everything*, the input and label text does not line up. The input text is one pixel lower than the label text.

HTML:

```
<div class="fieldgroup">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
</div><!--/.fieldgroup-->
```

CSS:

```
* {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: Arial;
}
.fieldgroup {
  position: relative;
}
input[type='text'],
label {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 16px;
  margin: 0;
  height: 30px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
}
input[type='text'] {
  border: none;
  background: green;
}
```

The plugin sets the label's `position` to `absolute` and the `top` and `left` properties to `0`.

[Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8Apy/5/).

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to do this using almost 100% CSS and avoid all the layout flow issues caused by `position: absolute;`

<kbd>**[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/YYhQ6/)**</kbd>

The trick is to wrap the `LABEL` around the text and `INPUT` element. Put the text inside of an element that can be given `display: inline-block; margin-right: -100%;`. This puts the text directly under the `INPUT`, which is given a transparent background so the text is visible through the `INPUT`.

Some Javascript is necessary to make the `INPUT` background opaque when the field has user input. There's no way around this at the moment… CSS can't "detect" a non-empty `INPUT` element.

Comment: Damned impressive, sir. *Damned* impressive.

Comment: One question: what does the second ! do in `toggleClass('notEmpty', !!input.val())`?

Comment: I'm having trouble getting the positioning to work (see fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/sX8Hq/

Comment: The `INPUT` was too wide to fit in the parent element, which caused it to drop down to a new row. When you set `width: 100%;` on the `INPUT`, it was 100% + border width + padding width. I tried a few solutions (http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/sX8Hq/1/, http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/sX8Hq/2/), but then I found that `box-sizing: border-box;` is supported by IE8+ (http://caniuse.com/#search=box-sizing). If you don't need to support IE7, this is the quickest solution: http://jsfiddle.net/thirdender/sX8Hq/3/ Also, make sure there is no space between the `SPAN` and `INPUT` elements.

Comment: Oh, and the `!!` basically converts `input.val()` to a boolean :-p `!input.val()` will return a boolean, but we need the inverse of that value, so two bangs will do. `!"" === true`, `!!"" === false`

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue by tweaking one of the CSS rules:

```
input[type='text'], label {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 1em;
    line-height: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
}
```

The trick is to set the container height to be the same as the line-height.

You can see the effect at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/d8Apy/7/

**Why this works???**

My guess is that browsers compute the height of the anonymous line boxes differently between input and label elements.  At least in FireFox, setting the line-height seems to do the trick.

I don't recall ever reading anything in the CSS3 spec related to these details.

**Note - Cross-Browser Effects**

I tested this in a few browsers and I discovered that if you set both height and line-height and use box-sizing, you get cross-browser issues.  However, if you use line-height and box-sizing, the results are consistent.  I have not tested with borders.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/d8Apy/12/
Just size your labels & input via line-height. so text-overlap each others since they'll be sitting on same line-height

```
* {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: Arial;
}
.fieldgroup {
    position: relative;

}
input[type='text'],
label {
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
    line-height:16px;
    Font-size:16px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;border:1px solid transparent
}
input[type='text'] {
    border: none;
    background: green;
}
```

Comment: I [updated my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d8Apy/5/) a few minutes after posting where I set the line-height for both elements to 16px. Didn't seem to work, though.

Comment: strange , and how about the fiddle i linked ? (http://jsfiddle.net/d8Apy/12/) OH, i see , you have kept height:30px. no need, line-height is giving it aa heigth